# How do I change date format in Android

Tags: android, date, format, date-format

I am displaying the date and time in Android with this format:
07-06-2017

How can I change it to the following format?
07/06/2017

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to change the date format

```
public String changeDateFormat(String dateInString, String outputFormat) {
       String inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date;
        String str = null;
        try {
            date = inputFormat.parse(dateInString);
            str = outputFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LogManager.e(e.getMessage());
        }
        return str;
    }
```